# Android AES decryption returning rare characters V2.0

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

Recently I've posted a question about this topic, but the thing turns a little weird when I tried to decrypt an AES String that was encoded on UTF8.

In the following lines I read the String AES encrypted which returns the following String: RnLObq9hdUDGp9S2pxC1qjQXekuf9g6i/5bQfKilYn4=

```
public static final String AesKey256 ="ZzRtNDNuY3J5cHRrM3kuLi4=";
//This reads the String and stores on res.getContents()
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult res= IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);
    if(res!=null){
        if (res.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Captura cancelada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            try {
                String cadena= decrypt(res.getContents());
                out.setText(cadena);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
//provide the res.getContents() to decrypt method, which is the String I've recently read
 private String decrypt(String cadena)throws Exception{
    SecretKeySpec keySpec= generateKey(AesKey256); //HERE
    Cipher c= Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,keySpec);
    byte[] decodedValue= Base64.decode(cadena, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decValue= c.doFinal(decodedValue);/* c.doFinal(decodedValue);*/
    String decryptedValue= new String((decValue), "UTF-8");
    return decryptedValue;
}
 private SecretKeySpec generateKey(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final MessageDigest digest= MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] bytes= password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    digest.update(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    byte[] key= digest.digest();
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec= new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    return secretKeySpec;
}
```

I am only using the decryption method but it still returning this characters:
[image: this shows after read the string]

I've spent hours looking for a solution, but nothing works for now... hope someone can give me a hand!

Best Regards!

EDIT
THIS IS HOW IT WAS ENCRYPTED IN C#

```
private const string AesIV256 = "IVFBWjJXU1gjRURDNFJGVg==";
        private const string AesKey256 = "ZzRtNDNuY3J5cHRrM3kuLi4=";

        public static string Encrypt(string text)
        {
            var sToEncrypt = text;
            var rj = new RijndaelManaged()
            {
                Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
                Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
                KeySize = 256,
                BlockSize = 256,
            };

            var key = Convert.FromBase64String(AesKey256);
            var IV = Convert.FromBase64String(AesIV256);

            var encryptor = rj.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);

            var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
            var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            var toEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sToEncrypt);

            csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
            csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

            var encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();

            return (Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
        }
```

Comment: How was it encrypted?

Comment: Ive update my post

Comment: So you’re not using the IV in the decryption? That will cause problems

Comment: Because it seems on c# code uses the CIPHER MODE.EBC and on Java side i have on AES_MODE= "AES/EBC/NoPadding" and if put the iv on cipher.init() it throws me an exception wich says that EBC not allow ivs

Comment: You just have to ignore the IV in the Java code, ECB in C# code does this as well. The way you're generating the key in Java and C# is completely different, I don't see how you can have generated that by porting the C# code to Java. If you try and decrypt by guessing you will have a *very* long way ahead of you. Key generation (from a random source) and key derivation are different things.

Comment: Using AES (or any block cipher) in ECB mode is insecure.

Comment: Your C# encryption code **is not using AES**. Rijndael with a block size of 256 is **not AES**.  Rijndael with a blocksize of 128 and a *key size* of 128, 192, or 256 is AES.

Comment: Then should i change the blocksize to 128 on c# code and try to encrypt and decrypt? Do you thing that might be the prob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it!

After a long time of searching thanks to all you guys who answered this post i used the bouncy castle library and i've decrypt the desired String by doing the following:

```
public static String decrypt(String valueToDecrypt) throws Exception {
    AESCrypt enc = new AESCrypt();
    return new String(enc.decryptInternal(valueToDecrypt)).trim();
}

private byte[] decryptInternal(String code) throws Exception {
    if (code == null || code.length() == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Empty string");
    }

    byte[] decrypted = null;
    try {


        byte[] key= SecretKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher c = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256), new ZeroBytePadding());
        CipherParameters params= new KeyParameter(key);`
        // false because its going to decrypt
        c.init(false,params);
        decrypted= GetData(c,(Base64.decode(code,Base64.DEFAULT));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return decrypted;
}


private static byte[] GetData(PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher, byte[] data) throws InvalidCipherTextException
{
    int minSize = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
    byte[] outBuf = new byte[minSize];
    int length1 = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, outBuf, 0);
    int length2 = cipher.doFinal(outBuf, length1);
    int actualLength = length1 + length2;
    byte[] cipherArray = new byte[actualLength];
    for (int x = 0; x < actualLength; x++) {
        cipherArray[x] = outBuf[x];
    }
    return cipherArray;
}
```